# Error connecting to oracle on windows 7 machine

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I've a .net 3.5 windows application which uses System.Data.OracleClient dll internally for Oracle database connectivity.The app works fine on a Windows XP machine.

When I port this application on a machine having Windows 7 OS,I get an error message when connecting to db:
"System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater."

This is fixed after installing Oracle 64 bit driver.But now am getting another error message:
"OCIEnvCreate failed with return code -1 but error message text was not available."

What could I be missing here please?

Thanks.

Comment: Stupid question but have you tried installing Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater?  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html

Comment: Is your machine running the 64 bits version of Windows 7?  If so, you need to check if your application is running in 32 bits or 64 bits mode.  There are two different versions of the Oracle driver, one for 64 bits and another for 32 bits.

Comment: Thanks @ GTG.Yes, its running on Windows 7 64 bit.How do I check if my app is running in 32 or 64 bits mode?Also, what is the name of this driver  dll please and where can I find that dll on Windows 7 machine?

Comment: If you have the source for the app, check the Project->Properties->Build tab, Platform target. If it is x86 the app is 32 bits. If it is Any Cpu, it will run as 64 bits on a 64 bits machine.  You can download the drivers at Oracle's website.

Answer (score 0):

The System.Data.OracleClient actually requires Oracle client software to be installed on the client system, so you probably have it installed on your XP machine but not on your Windows 7 machine.